# Docker Microsoft Package Hash Sum mismatch

Tags: docker

I'm running Docker to deploy to heroku and am getting an error message after running the following line:

```
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql mssql-tools \
    && apt-get install -y unixodbc-utf16 unixodbc-dev-utf16 php-pear
```

And the error:

```
Reading package lists...

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The Dockerfile has been working fine until this morning, where I found on the following url that the packages had been updated overnight. 
https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/

If anybody has any suggestions to this issue, I'd be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hitting the same issue here, so we can keep working, we've just updated our Dockerfile to ensure success code with the apt-get update like this

RUN apt-get -y update || :

Not a long term solution at all, but at least it allows you to keep working